# Python: Multithreading Copying - Threads are still alive

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Hello my problem is I have a multithreading copying class. And the copying works well, but the program is dont quit because the threads are still alive after copying.  I tried to build in a thread event, but this has no effect. The t.join() is never ending because the threads are alive. I also turned them daemonic, but this is unwanted, because the program ends but the threads are still alive when the program stops. Has anyone an idea what is wrong here? The Input of the class is a dataframe with the file source in first column and file destination in the other column

```
import shutil as sh
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Value, Lock, cpu_count 
import threading, os, time,queue


class ThreadedCopy():


totalFiles = 0
copyCount = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

def __init__(self,srcDst):        
    #fileList = srcDst['srcCol']
    self.fileQueue = queue.Queue()
    self.totalFiles = srcDst.shape[0]

    print(str(self.totalFiles) + " files to copy.")
    self.threadWorkerCopy(srcDst)


def CopyWorker(self):
    while True:
    #while True:
        fileRow = self.fileQueue.get()
        sh.copyfile(fileRow[1], fileRow[2])

        self.fileQueue.task_done()
        with self.lock:
            self.copyCount += 1
            percent = (self.copyCount * 100) / self.totalFiles
            if (percent%10==0):
                print(str(percent) + " percent copied.")

def threadWorkerCopy(self, srcDst):
    threads=[]
    for fileRow in srcDst.itertuples():
        self.fileQueue.put(fileRow)
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.CopyWorker,name='CopyThread')            
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        #threads.append(t)

    self.fileQueue.join()

ThreadedCopy(scrDstDf)
```

**EDIT**

If I key interupt the program It is hanging here:

```
<ipython-input-14-8d9a9b84e73f> in threadWorkerCopy(self, srcDst)
    380         self.stop_event.set()
    381         for thread in threads:
--> 382             thread.join()
    383 
    384 #ThreadedCopy(scrDstDf)

/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py in join(self, timeout)
   1052 
   1053         if timeout is None:
-> 1054             self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
   1055         else:
   1056             # the behavior of a negative timeout isn't documented, but

/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py in _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block, timeout)
   1068         if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
   1069             assert self._is_stopped
-> 1070         elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
   1071             lock.release()
   1072             self._stop()

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worker thread is blocked on `self.fileQueue.get()`, that's why it's not checking the stop event.

The most easiest way to solve this is to make the thread a daemon thread. That way they'll automatically get terminated when the main thread terminates.

If for some reason you don't want to/can't do this, then you'll need to wake up the worker thread by inserting a special marker value to the queue that your worker will check, if the worker sees this value from the queue, it should terminate itself.

Comment: I also tried to make them daemonic, the program is finsihed then, but If I check the alive threads with "import threading
threading.active_count()" , the threads are still alive. And If I execute the script over and over again, there are many alive threads then.

Comment: @Varlor: that's definitely not due to daemon threads. Note that `threading.active_count()` only counts the number of threads on the current process, so even if the thread somehow manages to survive, it will not be counted by `threading.active_count()` anyway. Those threads are started in the current instance of your program.

Comment: @Varlor Also, I note that you're using IPython, note that IPython starts off a number of background threads for its own internal use. I think these threads might be what you're seeing here.

Comment: Maybe you are right but this would mean every time I exxecute my Ipython script the active count would stack. But If I execute a simple print function the count is not rising. I also checked If it is the 8 processes I spawn in another part of my code but I think It isnt. Because when I do not create ThreadedCopy() in my code the thread count is not rising. So my question is, how would you do this with that special marker? Best regards! :)

Comment: "how would you do this with that special marker" Just put into the queue some value that you will never encounter during normal processing. For example, `sentinel = object(); fileQueue.put(sentinel)`; in the worker thread you just check if you received the sentinel value with something like: `fileRow = fileQueue.get(); if fileRow is sentinel: break out of the loop`

Comment: Why do you not want to just let daemon thread cleans things up though? Seems like you're just making things more complicated for yourself.

Comment: So I updated it with the daemonic process. Is that how you mean it? I also did the same procedure with multiprocessing Pool. And checking the Thread counter after me show me that there are no thread increasement. After the daemonic process it rises to 32 (cpu cores)

Comment: So i tested many things. You were right. I have a process in my script which starts processes. For some reason they are not stopping. This somehow causes the threads that are created afterward ( but not in the processes) do not stop either.